# How to correct invisible geometry

Tags: modeling, texturing, edges

I've some invisible edges on my model which generates bad textures as you can see below. 
How can I correct this ? 
It is from boolean operations.

Thanks ;) 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wall's geometry is really bad for the engine. Try to cut across the whole object everytime like on the picture. If the edges aren't align to any of the axes it's not a problem, but don't cut a hole to the middle of a simple face, because it will cause similar artifacts.
[image]